# Placeholder in Thymeleaf template cannot be found on null

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Trying to pass the variable on form submission to the result page, but it returns null every single time. No matter how many variations I've tried.

So I map get and post for login.html:

```
 @GetMapping("/login")
 public String greetingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("User2", new User());
    return "login";
}
@PostMapping("/login")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute User regUser) {
    //userRepository.save(regUser);
    //String teststr = regUser.getName();
    //System.out.println(teststr);
    return "result";
}
```

actual Login.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/demo/login}" th:object="${User2}" method="post">
        <p>Username: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
        <p>Password: <input type="text" th:field="*{password}" /></p>
        <p>Balance: <input type="text" th:field="*{balance}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

part of the User.java file:

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String password;

    private int balance;

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

and the result.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <p th:text="'username: ' + ${User.name}" />
    <p th:text="'password: ' + ${regUser != null ? regUser.password : 'NOT FOUND'}" />
    <p th:text="'balance: ' + ${model != null ? regUser.balance : 'NOT FOUND'}" />
    <a href="/demo/login">Submit another user?</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It keeps repeatedly throwing a null error on this line:

```
<p th:text="'username: ' + ${User.name}" />
```

specifically `${User.name}`, that looks like

> `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null`

So I've tried everything I can think of,

```
${User2.name}
${User}
${User2}
${regUser.name}
${teststr}
${#User.name}
```

etc....

It is very strange that if I uncomment `System.out.println(regUser.getName());`
It'll print the user's name just fine, but won't pass the variable. Is it my placeholder or can it not be passed as `th:text` because it's a `User` object? Please help I'm very confused!

Edit: Tutorial I followed(https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)
If you copy the tutorial it works just fine, but it is only passing a string. Although User.name would be a string variable...

Answer (score 0):

`@ModelAttribute` has an element named [`name`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html#name--). Its javadoc states

> The name of the model attribute to bind to.
>
> The default model attribute name is inferred from the declared
>   attribute type (i.e. the method parameter type or method return type),
>   based on the non-qualified class name: e.g. `"orderAddress"` for class
>   `"mypackage.OrderAddress"`, or `"orderAddressList"` for
>   `"List<mypackage.OrderAddress>"`.

Since you have provided a value for this element, Spring MVC uses the default value. As stated above, the default is inferred from the type of your parameter, which is `User`. If you follow the example, **that attribute name will therefore be `user`, not `User`**.

Your placeholder should read

```
 ${user.name}
```

This is also explained in the Spring reference documentation, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods)

> What happens when a model attribute name is not explicitly specified?
>   In such cases a default name is assigned to the model attribute based
>   on its type. For example if the method returns an object of type
>   `Account`, the default name used is `"account"`. You can change that
>   through the value of the `@ModelAttribute` annotation. If adding
>   attributes directly to the `Model`, use the appropriate overloaded
>   `addAttribute(..)` method - i.e., with or without an attribute name.

---

In your `@GetMapping`, you explicitly set the name of the model attribute

```
model.addAttribute("User2", new User());
```

You could do that for your `@PostMapping` example as well

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute(name = "User") User regUser) {
```